# Getting error when I try to release an Invoice via API

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm getting an error when I try to release an Invoice from Invoices and Memos screen (AR301000). The invoice is ready to be released, I even release the invoice manually and don't get any error.

This is the error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'PX.Data.PXInvalidOperationException: Operation failed ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The multi-part identifier "LocationExtAddress.LocationBAccountID" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "LocationExtAddress.LocationCD" could not be bound.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
```

This is my code in VS:

```
using (DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient())
{
    //Login part

    //Invoice data
    string invoiceType = "Invoice";
    string invoiceNbr = "T3-00000018";

    //Find the invoice to be released
    ARInvoice invoiceToFind = new ARInvoice
    {
        Type = new StringSearch { Value = invoiceType },
        ReferenceNbr = new StringSearch { Value = invoiceNbr },
        Hold = new BooleanValue { Value = false }
    };

    ARInvoice invoice = (ARInvoice)client.Get(invoiceToFind);

    //Release invoice
    InvokeResult invokeResult = client.Invoke(invoice, new ReleaseARInvoice());

    //Monitor the status of the process
    ProcessResult processResult = LongRunProcessor.GetProcessResult(client, invokeResult);

    //Get the confirmed shipment
    invoice = (ARInvoice)client.Get(new ARInvoice { ID = processResult.EntityId });

    //Display the summary of the invoice
    txtType.Text = invoice.Type.Value;
    txtNumber.Text = invoice.ReferenceNbr.Value;
    txtStatus.Text = invoice.Status.Value;

    client.Logout();
}
```

Specifically I get that error in "client.Invoke".

Comment: Are you able to release the invoice through the Acumatica UI?

Comment: Yes, and I don't have any issue to release the invoices through the Acumatica UI. @Kulvir

Comment: What version of the endpoint are you using?  Did you extend it for this entity?  In endpoint 18.200.001, I don't see an entity for ARInvoice.  Instead, I only see an entity called Invoice.  And the Release Action is called ReleaseInvoice.

Comment: I'm using version 17.200.001, yes, I extended it for the entity, I modified the name of the endpoint objects as you say but I still getting the same error. @DianeCawley

Comment: Can you try again by using the Invoice entity --- the default entity that is specified in the Default endpoint (even in your extended endpoint)?  I believe that the root problem is your extended entity ARInvoice is missing some crucial fields that are in the Invoice entity and that is what is causing yout error.

Comment: I tried to release the invoice using the default entity in the Default endpoint but I still getting the same error. @DianeCawley